# Repeating rows in excel could not work with this set of codes

Tags: python, excel, rows, repeat

My question is as follows:
Purpose of my program: To repeat the data from another excel file 3 times before moving on to the next set of data.
e.g.
Desired Output:

```
    23   25   27 
    23   25   27 
    23   25   27 
    28   4    21 
    28   4    21 
    28   4    21
```

My current (error) output is:
e.g.
Error Output:

```
    23    25    27
    28    4    21
```

My codes are as follows. Why can't I just repeat my codes 3 times for column K, L and M by just repeating the codes and changing the row number accordingly? It shows the error output instead of the desired output. :( 
Thank you very much for reading and helping!

```
 #>>>>>>>>>>>SEPERATE LIST SHOWN IN PYTHON PROGRAM (i.e. dataX, data Y, data Z), -START- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<#

     CRS=[] 
     dataX=[sheet.cell_value(1, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
     dataY=[sheet.cell_value(2, col) for ju in range(4)for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
     dataBin = [sheet.cell_value(6, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]

     for nm in range (int(ND)):         #for nm in range of ND
         CRS.append((dataX[nm+6],dataY[nm+6],dataBin[nm+6]))

     print CRS
     print ""

     workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
     sheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet1')

     for index, value in enumerate(dataBin):

         sheet.write( 3, index, value)
         sheet.write( 1, index, value)
         sheet.write( 2, index, value)
```

(cont'd below) #ERROR MOST LIKELY STARTS HERE

```
         for np in range(int(ND)):          

        #COLUMN K = X COORDINATE
             sheet1.write(np+30,10,CRS[np][0])  #np+30 == row. 10== column K
             sheet1.write(np+31,10,CRS[np][0])  #np+31 == row. 11== column K,
             sheet1.write(np+32,10,CRS[np][0])  #np+32 == row. 12== column K

        #COLUMN L = Y COORDINATE
             sheet1.write(np+30,11,CRS[np][1])  #np+30 == row. 10 == column L
             sheet1.write(np+31,11,CRS[np][1])  #np+31 == row. 11 == column L
             sheet1.write(np+32,11,CRS[np][1])  #np+32 == row. 12 == column L

        #COLUMN M = SOFT BIN
             sheet1.write(np+30,12,CRS[np][2])  #np+30 == row. 10 == column M
             sheet1.write(np+31,12,CRS[np][2])  #np+31 == row. 11 == column M
             sheet1.write(np+32,12,CRS[np][2])  #np+32 == row. 12 == column M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the loop when np = 10, your three rows (np+30, np+31, np+32) will equate to rows 40,41 and 42.

On the next loop when np = 11, your three rows will equate to 41,42,43, thus overwriting two of your previous lines.

I expect if you look at your output, the last item would be in triplicate as desired.

Try multiplying np by 3.

```
(np*3)+30...

10*3+30=60
10*3+31=61
10*3+32=62
11*3+30=63
11*3+31=64
11*3+32=65
12*3+30=66 etc
```

Comment: Thank you for the great help! I've found another method in doing this, by creating a loop. I.e. np+=3 instead of having to times 3. But I'll still be giving you the tick :)